# Animate.css link

Tags: html, css

I included the following link in the head section of my html page but the animation is not working:

An animated element I tried this and it is working. Do I need to write animate__animated instead of only animated ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.0/animate.min.css" />
```

I also added bootstrap links in my original code. Bootstrap links are working but not animation. Is there any other link need to add?

```
<div class="container">
   <header class="animated slideInDown text-center text-white p-5">
   <h1 class="display-4"> Using Animation! </h1>
   </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to call the right classes for it to work and activate.
you must call `animate__animated` and just copy the effect from their website and paste it and it should work.

Note that when I copied their class it was `animate__slideInDown` not `slideInDown`.

```
<div class="container">
        <header class="animate__animated  animate__slideInDown text-center  p-5">
            <h1 class="display-4"> Using Animation! </h1>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the right answer, the poster was using the old API and classes for animate.css, they introduced breaking changes in v4.

Comment: ya that's why we should always check the documentation xD

Answer (score 0):

It could be that for some animations you need all librarys from bootstrap (also js und jquery)
also bootstrap has no animations
what you mean is mdboostrap
try following this guid -> https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/

Comment: No buddy you don't need any. All you need is to call the library using a CDN or to download it and use its classes.